# secure iPhone to server communication so that only my app can post data?

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iPhone app that has to post some data to a server e.g. say user's votes for on a topic. Here's the problem:

I want to implement some form of encryption so that only my iPhone clients can post votes to the server, no other devices/sources may post data.

I am not using usernames/passwords, and the server has REST interfaces defined to read/post data.

any ideas? appreciate any/all help.

--
MI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest challenge/response certification of your application.  embed a key in the app, the server sends a message, you post your data and a computation is done to the challenge data and return that also.